# how to display only time in UIDatePicker iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiactionsheet

In my app i am displaying a `UIDateTimePicker` in action sheet through code. it is working fine.
But i don't want to display date and day.How this can be done.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

code:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Select     Date",@"Selecte Date")delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Done",@"Done")
destructiveButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel",@"Cancel")
otherButtonTitles:nil];  


    actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
  UIDatePicker  *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 270)];
    //datePicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
//   datePicker.dataSource = self;
//datePicker.delegate = self;
    [actionSheet addSubview:datePicker];
    [datePicker release];

    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
    [actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 500)];
  [actionSheet release];
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
```

Comment: display the datepicker as a subview of UIActionSheet. Then you can use the didDismissWithButtonIndex delegate from UIActionSheetDelegate to dismiss the datepicker

Answer (score 7):

Set the `datePickerMode` property to one of the following:

```
typedef enum {
   UIDatePickerModeTime,
   UIDatePickerModeDate,
   UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime,
   UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer
} UIDatePickerMode;
```

Answer (score 3):

In Swift:

```
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Time
```

Answer (score 2):

```
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
```